# Volume of the solid generated by revolving the region R enclosed by the curve - Disk and Shell method

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region $R$ enclosed by the curve $y=x^3$, the $x$-axis and the line $x=1$.

(About the line $y=1$ using the disk and shell method.)

Comment: I get 5pi/14 for the disk method. It is the shell method i cant get to equal the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Disk Method, $$V=\int_{0}^1\pi[1^2-(1-y)^2]dx=\pi\int_{0}^1[2y-y^2]dx=\pi\int_{0}^1[2x^3-x^6]dx=\dots=\frac{5\pi}{14}$$ and by using the Shell Method,
$$V=\int_{0}^1\big[2\pi(1-y)\cdot (1-x)dy\big]=\int_{0}^1\big[2\pi(1-y)\cdot (1-\sqrt[3]y)dy\big]=\dots=\frac{5\pi}{14}$$

**Edit:** Note that $2\pi(1-y)$ is the circumference of the circle obtained by rotating the point $(x,y)$ from the curve $y=x^3$ about the line $y=1$. Also, $(1-\sqrt[3]y)dy$ is the area of the sliced element of the region.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the disk method down fine, so let's look at the shell method. When describing our shells, we want to find the radius and height of each shell. Notice that we will be integrating along the $y$ values.

When $y = y_0$, for $0 \leq y_0 \leq 1$, the radius of the shell will be $1-y_0$ (the vertical distance from the line $y=1$ to $y_0$). The height of the shell will be $1-y_0^{1/3}$, which is the difference in the $x$ values for the curves $x=1$ and $x^3 = y$ at $y=y_0$.

Then each shell has the volume $2\pi rh \, dy$, or in this case, $2 \pi (1-y_0)(1-y_0^{1/3}) \, dy$.

This gives us the integral $\int\limits_0^1 2 \pi (1-y_0)(1-y_0^{1/3}) \, dy = \frac{5\pi}{14}$.